# Mysql search group or specific word in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have products. The clients wants that when the title of the product is like "Glass protector for Lenovo Vibe C2" and the user searches "glass protector c2" to show the product. I am building the query with a like condition, but it is working with words like "glass protector" or "vibe c2", only with consecutive words ...

Here is the query:

```
$query = Product::find()->joinWith('translation')->joinWith('cats')->joinWith('cats.page')->joinWith('cats.page.parent')->where($whereString);
$whereString .= " AND ( 
                        (
                            product_cat.page_id = '" . $_GET['product_cat'] . "' 
                            OR 
                            parent.id = '" . $_GET['product_cat'] . "' 
                            ) 
                            AND 
                            (
                                page_title LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%' 
                                OR
                                short_description LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'  
                                OR 
                                key_words LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'      
                                )
                            )";
```

The title of the product is : "Glass protector for Lenovo Vibe C2"

The user searches for "Glass protector" => everything is OK, the product is shown.

BUT when the user searches for "Glass protector C2" => nothing is shown ... Does not have this product in the database.

Comment: Please clarify what your issue is and preferably also some examples of input data and expected results.

Comment: i add the example in post

Comment: Please try with REGEXP clause instead of LIKE clause.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but in your original code, you have a couple of [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). When building SQL statements, always make sure to use prepared statements and properly escape all externally provided data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a search that using regular expressions breaks up the search string to indidvidual words with wildcards in between.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE page_title REGEXP CONCAT('.*', REPLACE('Glass protector C2', ' ', '.*'), '.*')
```

So this would then need to be done for all 3 columns and of course with the hard coded search string replaced with the variable used in the quetion

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a full text search in order to achieve this, as the like operator is not built for the kind of queries you are trying to run.

You would first need to create a full text index on the column you want to search.
In your example, the index creation command would look like that -

```
ALTER TABLE Product
ADD FULLTEXT(page_title, short_description,…)
```

Once the index is created, you can query it using full text searches, in your example the right choice would probably be using a boolean full text search.
You can do that like so -

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE MATCH (page_title, short_description)
    AGAINST ('+vibe +c2' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

You can lookup the documentation for more reference - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html